# Поиск по статьям и новостям на сайте

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql, поиск, sphinx

Интересует, целесообразность использовать sphinx или иную поисковую машину для организации поиска по сайту. Хотелось бы, чтобы поиск сортировался по наиболее подходящему варианту. И Конечно поиск должен происходить по полям новостей, статей и категорий. То есть несколько таблиц. Также фильтр по тегу статьи.

С поисковыми машинами ранее не работал. База данных на PostgreSQL.

Как такой поиск возможно организовать и необходимо ли здесь использовать Sphinx или другой подобный инструмент?

У меня мысли использовать Full Text Index PostgreSQL. Он вроде должен автоматически сортировать по количеству совпадений. Но не знаю как делать поиск по нескольким таблицам. Наверное сделать представление, объединив в нём  эти таблицы? И уже по представлению делать поиск?

Comment: Вы можете собрать полнотекстовый индекс в одной таблице, объединив несколько полей из разных таблиц + назначить разные веса

Comment: Ого, это очень удобно, а можете показать пример как это делается?

Comment: Просто понятно, как делать веса для полей, но вот как использовать поля из разных таблиц не понятно.

Comment: пробуйте подзапросы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, но в реальности нужен еще словарь.

```
create table t1 (
  id int,
  title varchar(128),
  fts tsvector
);

create table t2 (
  id int,
  title2 varchar(128)
);

insert into t1(id, title) values (1, 'cow');
insert into t2(id, title2) values (1, 'milk');


UPDATE t1 as target 
        SET fts =
            setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(title, '')), 'A') ||
            setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce((select title2 from t2 where id = target.id) ,'')), 'B');

select * from t1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7e82d/22

Comment: Да, спасибо, я так понимаю поле fts для демонстрации? Просто не особо понял назначение таблицы t1. Как я смотрел по документациям, хранить tsvector не нужно. Только нужно индекс создать, а tsvector при каждом запрос генерировать для конкретных полей.

Comment: @iproger, хранить его нужно, к сожалению, и gin index по нему построить нужно, в противном случае накладные расходы сильно возрастают. Хотя все от размера бд зависит. У нас 200GB данных, поэтому приходится хранить.

Comment: Ага, понял, хранить чтобы каждый раз его не строить. Спасибо!) То есть запрос на поиск уже выглядеть будет  примерно так: SELECT id, title FROM t1 WHERE
  fts @@ to_tsquery('bjarne <-> stroustrup');

Comment: @iproger, совершенно точно.